# PHP member login system (yes again)

Tags: php

Hey all im struggling with a simple membership system. I have coded for a while but not much in php (mainly java) so would appreciate any help or suggestions on what to look at. I always seem to look over simple mistakes and though I have checked it in a syntax checker i'm sure its something very minor

here goes..

my login.php file allows a user to login if they have a username and password and if not sends appropriate responses. But when I log in with a existing username and password it goes to the next page which display your name and link to go to the members section, but when the link is clicked the member section will not seem to recognise my $_SESSION values and therefore asks the user to login again.

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION['$userid'];
$username = $_SESSION['$username'];
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Member system - login</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $form = "<form action='./login.php' method='post'>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>username :</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='user'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>password :</td>
        <td><input type='password' name='password'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='loginbtn' value='Login'/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>";

if($_POST['loginbtn']) {
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($user) {
        if($password) {
            require("connect.php");

            $password = md5(md5("12345".$password."54321"));
            //make sure login info correct
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$user'");
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

            if($numrows == 1) {
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                $dbid = $row['id'];
                $dbuser = $row['username'];
                $dbpass = $row['password'];
                $dbactive = $row['active'];

                if($password == $dbpass) {
                    if($dbactive == 1) {
                        //set seesion info
                        $_SESSION['userid'] = $dbid;
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;

                        echo "you have been logged in as <b>$dbuser</b> <a href='./member.php'>click here</a> to go to the member page";
                    }
                    else 
                        echo "You must be an active member. $form";
                }
                else
                    echo "you did not enter the correct password. $form";
            }
            else                    
                echo "The user name you entered was not found. $form";

            mysql_close();
        }
        else
            echo "you must enter your password. $form";
    }
    else
        echo "you must enter a user name. $form";
    }
else
 echo $form;
?>
```

This is my login form which does the bulk of the work

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION['$userid'];
$username = $_SESSION['$username'];
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Member system : Members</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if($username && $userid) {
        echo "Welcome <b>$username</b>, <a href='./logout.php'>logout</a>";
    }
    else 
        echo "Please login in to veiw this page <a href='./login.php'>Login in</a>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my member form which seems to not recognise the session and ask for the user to login again.

i know this is the embarrassingly obvious to someone and i apologise for my ignorance but i will learn from this, so if someone could help ill be very grateful.

Regards 
Mike

Comment: Why are you using session variables containing a dollar sign? Thats confusing and can cause errors. `$_SESSION['$userid'];` == BAD JOO JOO.

Comment: Your password system makes me cringe. Better than plaintext I suppose! Check out: [Why are common hashing functions such as md5() and sha1() unsuitable for passwords? ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Comment: Yet again its somthing so stupid yes why did i use $_SESSION['$userid'];, thanks for your quick replies people cant believe it was that simple. Thanks cillosis bang on the money. And thanks for your tip mkaatman im looking into it as i type. Great help and I thought I was going to get slaughtered.

Comment: @Mike - You should mark the posted answer as the accepted answer since it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is a little mistake. In the first script you use $_SESSION['userid'], and in the second one $_SESSION['$userid] (with a dollar inside the key).

I don't know exactly if that solves your problem, but try to replace:

```
if($username && $userid) {
```

with this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userid'],$_SESSION['username'])) {
```

Greetings Jokus!

Comment: yeah they both work great though it works also without the   if(isset($_SESSION['userid'],$_SESSION['username'])) {. thanks again much love.